# Configure apache to handle all requests via single index.php

Tags: php, apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I've inherited ugly piece of php which must handle all requests via single index.php.

index.php  generates different web-pages using smarty with embedded business-logic depending on wisited url.

How can I configure apache2/php5 to handle all requests via index.php?

UPDATE: are there any alternatives to mod-rewrite to use here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, without `mod_rewrite`. `mod_rewrite` is the answer, of course, but this uses `mod_alias`:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/(?<!index\.php)(.*) http://example.com/index.php
```

This should match anything that isn't preceded by `index.php` and issue a permanant redirect to the correct index.php.  Note that you'll need to specify the full location as the target.

**Updated**  I've tested the above and it needs Apache 2.0+ as it uses PCRE.  If you need the actual path appending to `index.php`, then append `$1` to the redirect path.

Answer (score 2):

```
LoadModule rewrite_module     /usr/lib/apache/modules/mod_rewrite.so

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?index.php$
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: (path to mod_rewrite may be different, and may be on by default in apache2, I forget, this is copied from my apache 1.3 install)

Answer (score 2):

Save the following into a file named **.htaccess** in your web root.

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Web Directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect certain folders from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(protected|directories) - [F,L]

# Rewrite URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may do this with a mod_rewrite rule.

```
#.htaccess code
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: I think you need the RewriteCond to avoid looping

Comment: Likely. My mod_rewrite is rusty.

Answer (score 1):

This is what works with my Wordpress install:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

The two RewriteCond lines allow serving existing files: without them you'd have to pass images and stylesheets through index.php too.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite a bit more simple than any of these, and you are asking for a solution without mod_rewrite, so:

```
 Alias /static/  /path/to/static/files/
 Alias /         /path/to/script.php/
```

If you have no static files, you can, of course, omit the first line (but it usually answers the follow up of "how do I make exceptions").

As a dirty hack for older Apache (1.x), you can use the 404 handler and DocumentRoot an empty directory, but that's way ugly.  I've seen it recommended before, but that was a long while ago when it was necessary.  It might help in odd cases.